# Winform C#：how to get the parent ToolMenuStrip control from her ToolMenuStripItem？

Tags: c#, winforms

Now I'm implementing the Click event of ToolStripMenuItem,but I need to know which ToolMenuStrip this control belong . what should I do?

Comment: Try [Owner or Parent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.owner?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of this question ,I've solved this problem.I show the solution in the below.

like this:

```
    var parent=ToolStripMenuItem.Owner;
    var toolStripMenu=(ToolStripMenu)parent;
```

and this toolStripMenu is based on a button,so if I wanna get the button,it should be like this:

```
    var btn=toolStripMenu.SourceControl;
```

That's all.